# blocking user interaction with underlying views

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uiview

In my app, i have an overlay view, which is displayed when some processing and networking is happening. It is just a semitransparent view (subclass of UIView) with a loading indicator on it, filling the whole screen.

I want to prevent any of the underlying views to recieve user-interaction (e.g. a underlying table view should not be scrolled, a button not be pressed).

What is the best way i can do this from within the overlay view?

Comment: Is your overlay view on the top of view stack?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just set the `userInteractionEnabled` property for the overlay view to `YES`. This will cause all touch events to occur on the overlay view and not be passed to the underlying views.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, i've tried setting it in init as well as in loadView, in both cases, the buttons below still do receive touch events.

Comment: @Ahti: Are you using Interface Builder at all? (I don't think you are, but just making sure.)

Comment: @Ahti: I had some sprite node below that was getting hit.  I modified hitTest:withEvent: to return a dummy button offscreen for the overlay itself.  The button absorbs the hits and does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Just set property `userInteractionEnabled` of your *semitransparent overlay view* to YES.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to use these 2 methods:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

right before doing the heavy processing operations, and after completing them respectively.

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me. It will work regardless of where your overlay is in the view hierarchy. My overlay was on a scrollview, and this was the only way I could prevent scrolling without making a change to the scrollview's controller (since the overlay is used by several controllers)

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the overlay view and all of its parent views do not have `userInteractionEnabled` set to NO, are not hidden, and do not have an `alpha` less than 0.01. Then the user's touches will interact with the overlay instead of the views visible behind it. Also be aware that it will not block interaction in an area that is not covered by its superviews: even if your view covers the whole screen, if its parent is just 10x10 then it will only block interaction within that 10x10 area covered by its parent.

You may also need to ensure that `resignFirstResponder` is called on any existing first responder, or the user will still be able to interact with it via the keyboard.