# beginIgnoringInteractionEvents or userInteractionEnabled = NO not working as expected

Tags: ios

I'm facing a very strange issue with user interactions while showing an overlay view with progress indicator.

On the main view I've previous & next buttons and clicking on the next button, I make a web service call and during that process I show an overlay view with progress indicator as follows.

```
    [self createProgressViewWithMessage:@"Loading..."];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.inProgressView];
    [self.inProgressView becomeFirstResponder];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(search:) toTarget:self
                           withObject:info];
```

After successful retrieval, I'll update the records list and also perform enabling and disabling previous  & next buttons. While displaying the overlay view, clicking on either previous or next buttons, the events are being queued and getting called after the web service call is finished. To avoid these queuing stuff, I've tried multiple ways like calling     `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents]`
before creating the progress view and calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents]` after the web service call is finished but still the events are getting called after that.

Tried even making the main view by setting `userInteractionEnabled = NO` while the overlay view is present but still of no use.

Tried all possible ways but still of no use. Don't know why the events are being queued and getting called after the web service call is finished.

Can someone help me in resolving this issue? I don't want the events to be queued while the overlay view is shown. I mean the events should not be passed to the previous and next buttons which are on the main view while the overlay view is in progress.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit counter intuitive, but you actually want your overlay to be interaction enabled. In that case, it will receive the touch events and they will not be passed to the buttons and other views underneath:

```
    // Stop interacting with buttons underneath while async operation in progress.
    myOverlayView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

See this question [blocking user interaction with underlying views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271732/blocking-user-interaction-with-underlying-views)

Answer (score 0):

you can set `userInteractionEnabled = NO` but not your main view 
but your overlay view(and your overlay view must cover your button)
or your can just disable your button

Comment: I've tried setting the overlay view userInteractionEnabled = NO and even made the buttons disabled. The events are getting fired after my web service call is done. They are not getting fired when the web service is in progress. All the events are getting queued and getting fired once the web service call is completed.

Comment: then the problem may not be the button be trigger
i need to see more code about 
what's your button do
how do you make a web service request
what do you do after you web service call is completed